# Do I need to create both an extension & packaged app if I want chrome.socket and Context Menus?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome extension/app that requires

- communicate with Intranet services in UDP binary protocol using `chrome.socket` APIs
- need to extract DOM content from non-app web pages. This could be done using bookmarklet, [Browser Actions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html), [page actions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html), or chrome context menus.

There are two `chrome.contextMenus` APIs

- http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus.html
- http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html

One for Packaged App, another for Extensions. The former only insert contextMenus to Packages Apps, not normal web pages.

If I need both `chrome.socket` & invoking from normal webpage capability, do I need to create both an extension as well as an app? That would be very confusing to end users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need both the app and the extension. Apps are intentionally devoid of APIs that modify web pages. That's where extensions come in.

I ran into the same problem and had to make two separate apps for exactly the same reasons. (JSTorrent contextmenu extension && JSTorrent).

I believe there are ways to trigger the install dialog from one to the other, but I have not tried to do this yet. If somebody had examples for how to do this, that would be great to add here!

Comment: An api for that has just been proposed: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NcrMJODhrKNxASCdC_zR_qJLA58MXdBCRIsBiR7URZs

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [<webview>](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/webview_tag.html) in an app. You'll be able to display web content there, and you can more easily communicate between the app and the content. It will result in a single installable item.

Comment: Do app-defined context menus appear in embedded `<webview>` app content?

Comment: At the moment, no. But the question text suggested the asker was flexible about the actual UI mechanism (vs. the title, which named only one mechanism), so the suggestion is potentially relevant.